# install4j how to disable "install into a different directory" option

Tags: install4j

I am trying to come up with an upgrade path with install4j. 
When an older release is installed on the box on running the installer i see a pop window asking whether to update the existing or install into a different directory.

How to modify this panel? I would like to give options like 
-Update the existing 
-Uninstall the existing

One more i see that the path being taken when we run the same version (reinstall/repair) and newer version (upgrade) is same. Is there a way that we can distinguish them and present a different panel and different sequence of dialogs.

How to prevent installs of older version over newer versions? Say when a run of 3.0 version is done on a box with 2.0 version.

In all the above scenarios i am maintaining the same application id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of these scenarios can be realized, but you have to program them.

You can display different screens depending on arbitrary conditions. The [ApplicationRegistry](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/api/com/install4j/api/ApplicationRegistry.html) class helps you to get information on the already installed version.

To see an example for how to use it, add a "Run script" action to the "Startup" node of your installer, edit the "Script" property and click on the "Code gallery" tool bar button. In the code gallery, see the "Check if already installed" code snippet